# React-google-charts, ColumnChart returns Unhandled rejection Error: Failed to set DataTable from data props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I'm trying to render a `ColumnChart` from `react-google-charts` 
https://rakannimer.github.io/react-google-charts/#/examples/ColumnChart?_k=xit9kl

When rendering, the console logs the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Failed to set DataTable from data props !
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.dataTable.getNumberOfRows is not a function
```

I believe I have the props formatted correctly...

```
    <Chart
      chartType='ColumnChart'
      data={this.formatData()}
      graph_id=''
      width='100%'
      height='500px'
      legend_toggle
    />
```

`formatData()` returns the following data structure...

```
Array[2]
  0:Array[3]
    0:"Crime Category"
    1:Array[63]
    2:Object
  1:Array[33]
    0:Array[65]
      0:"Vikings"
      1:0
      2:0
      3:0
      4:0
      5:7
      ...
```

This seems to comport perfectly with the prescribed data structure in the documentation, which looks like this...

```
  "data":[
    [
      "Genre",
      "Fantasy & Sci Fi",
      "Romance",
      "Mystery/Crime",
      "General",
      "Western",
      "Literature",
      {"role":"annotation"}
    ],
    ["2010",10,24,20,32,18,5,""],
    ["2020",16,22,23,30,16,9,""],
    ["2030",28,19,29,30,12,13,""]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misreading the data structure. The problem was solved by returning an array of all items rather than an array of 2 items with the remaining attributes nested in those. This is the working code...

```
const columns = teamList.map(team => {
  const newArray = Object.keys(team['teamCrimeCategorySum'])
    .sort()
    .map(key => {
      return team['teamCrimeCategorySum'][key]
    })
  return [`${team.name}`, ...newArray, '']
}) 

return [
  [
    'Crime Category',
    ...categories.map(category => `${category.name}`),
    {'role':'annotation'}
  ],
  ...columns
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, with a slightly different cause, so I thought I'd add this in incase anyone else comes across this:

My data looked like this:

`data = [["Room 524", 50], ["Room 123", 23], ["Room 523", 17], ["Room 964", 12], ["Room 012", 56], ["Room 125", 35]]`

Adding in a header row fixed the issue.

`data = [["Title A", "Title B"], ["Room 524", 50], ["Room 123", 23], ["Room 523", 17], ["Room 964", 12], ["Room 012", 56], ["Room 125", 35]];`